# Compare a field of a string in a file with a variable in shell

Tags: regex, shell, date, awk, compare

I have a phone book file `rubrica.txt`, which contains records (name, second name, phone number, telephone number, date, date in seconds) on each line like that (each entry is separated by a space):

```
andrea mantovani 3476589456 0451234567 2016/05/16 1463419858190456946
marco verratti 1265897654 3057634987 2016/05/16 1463419948782978926
zlatan ibrahimovic 2937485929 1938472639 2016/05/16 1463420078149548084
cesc fabregas 5641287659 3456789123 2016/05/16 1463420324574207170
andrea mantovani 3402948586 0459687124 2016/05/17 1463500810082293135
marco rossi 3951326586 0458793540 2016/05/17 1463500836814967504
```

I want to view on output all contacts that have been added after a date inserted by me.

At first I read the date that I want and convert it to seconds with the following script:

```
echo "Digit the date"
read date_jap              #read a date(yyyy/mm/dd)                     
data_sec=$(date +%s -d $data_jap)   #convert the date in sec
```

This part of code function. I explain that to be more clear.

I don't know how can I compare this date with the date (the last entry) in file `rubrica.txt`.

I used:

```
cat $RUBRICA | awk '/$data_sec < \6/ { print }'
```

to display all contacts whose date in seconds in the field 6 of the line (example taking my file at the first line: `1463419858190456946`) is greater than `date_sec`.

`$data_sec < \6` I know is incorrect. I must fix it.

Comment: I don't think you need to convert the date to seconds. Since you have your date in the format YYYY/MM/DD, simply lexicographical comparision would be sufficient.

Comment: `awk '{if ($6 > ENVIRON["data_sec"]) print}'` should work. Do not forget to export `data_sec` otherwise it won't be seen by `awk`. Another option:
`awk "{if (\$6 > $data_sec) print}"` here it is no longer necessary to export `$data_sec`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Or use `awk -v dsec="$data_sec"`

Comment: @user1934428 But the date in seconds has different values for the same day.

Comment: @BenjaminW. : Sorry, my mistake. I failed to notice that you are requiring precision to the second. Of course, in this case you can ignore the formatted date part, because the time stamp is fully encoded in the seconds field. You just need numeric comparision instead of lexicographic one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your date in seconds is the value of the third record and assign that:

```
data_sec=1463420078149548084
```

Now we get this value into awk using `-v`, then compare the sixth field to it:

```
$ awk -v mydate="$data_sec" '$6 > mydate' rubrica.txt
cesc fabregas 5641287659 3456789123 2016/05/16 1463420324574207170
andrea mantovani 3402948586 0459687124 2016/05/17 1463500810082293135
marco rossi 3951326586 0458793540 2016/05/17 1463500836814967504
```

If the expression `$6 > mydate` evaluates to true, the record gets printed.